What if gas molecules collide inelastically?
I know that inelastic collision ($e=0$) of gas molecules does not make sense, but I wonder, if somehow hypothetically gas molecules made inelastic collision with the container in which it is filled and also made inelastic collision with other gas molecules.
What would be it's effect on Pressure exerted on the walls of the container and Velocity of gas molecules and also the effect in Temperature.
(What would be the scenario in both the cases of ideal as well as real gas)


I know that inelastic collision(e=0) of gas molecules does not make sense, but I wonder, if somehow hypothetically gas molecules made inelastic collision with the container in which it is filled and also made inelastic collision with other gas molecules.

Inelastic collisions between molecules are possible, as well as between molecules and the walls of the container.
Molecules have internal degrees of freedom - notably the rotational, vibrational, and electronic ones. Electronic degrees of freedom are typiclaly not activated at reasonable temperatures, but the rotational and vibrational degrees of freedom are account for in the equipartition theorem and affect, e.g., heat capacity. The activation of vibrational degrees of freedom at higher temperature also explains why heat capacity is temperature-dependent.
Collisions with the walls of a container would simply result in the dissipation of energy and cooling of the gas. This however works in both ways, as the walls of the container also transfer energy when molecules collide with them. Thus, if a cold reservoir is brought into a hot room, the gas inside will eventually heat up, whereas if a warm gas is brought into cold, the gas eventually cools down. The pressure can then be calculated as a function of temperature, using the equation of state.
Update
@MichaelSeifert suggested in the comments a concise formulation of the above, which I find particularly clear, and include here verbatim:

It's also worth noting that energy can be exchanged between the translational degrees of freedom and the internal degrees of freedom. Effectively, we can treat the different types of degrees of freedom as subsystems that are in thermal equilibrium. If we somehow set up a gas with lots of translational KE but no rotational KE, we would expect that over time energy would be transferred to rotations, but that eventually we'd reach an equilibrium where collisions are on average transferring equal amounts of energy from rotational to translational KE as from translational to rotational


It's also worth noting that energy can be exchanged between the translational degrees of freedom and the internal degrees of freedom.  Effectively, we can treat the different types of degrees of freedom as subsystems that are in thermal equilibrium.  If we somehow set up a gas with lots of translational KE but no rotational KE, we would expect that over time energy would be transferred to rotations, but that eventually we'd reach an equilibrium where collisions are on average transferring equal amounts of energy from rotational to translational KE as from translational to rotational.

@MichaelSeifert This is what I tried to explain... if you don't mind, I would include your comment in the answer.

Feel free to include it!

In addition to the good answer of @Roger V. :
When you heat your gas to a temperature high enough, the electronic degrees of freedom start to participate in the energy distribution as well.
Electronic excitations are the way heated gas emits light.
Of course, if you prevent light from escaping the gas, it gets absorbed at some point. This is how the gas may get in thermodynamic equilibrium with the electromagnetic radiation.
By heating even more, you may find that the gas has "chemical" degrees of freedom - some molecules will separate into atoms or free electrons + ions (depending on the gas nature and the temperatures involved).
And if you have some really, really good source of heat, you may find different degrees of freedom (e.g. nuclear) to excite.


I know that inelastic collision (e=0) of gas molecules does not make sense...

They do.

..., but I wonder, if somehow hypothetically gas molecules made inelastic collision with the container in which it is filled and also made inelastic collision with other gas molecules.

The gas molecules could get stuck in the wall (adsorption), or even combine together to create  denser phase (e.g. condensation of water vapor into droplets). This condensation happens only if proper conditions are met (enough vapor, low enough temperature).

What would be it's effect on Pressure exerted on the walls of the container

During adsorption, the captured molecule doesn't bounce back, so it gives only half an impulse to the walls of what it would give were it bounce back. So if in a short time, more molecules get adsorbed than desorbed, net pressure on the walls is slightly lower. When the wall has enough adsorbed molecules, they also get ejected back into gas randomly, and dynamical equilibrium can establish itself; then pressure is again what the equation of state predicts for the given volume, number of gas particles and temperature.

and Velocity of gas molecules and also the effect in Temperature.

Condensation usually emits heat, so temperature of the condensed droplets will be somewhat higher than the gas they have grown from, and if many droplets condense, the whole system including the gas increases its temperature, and rejects noticeable heat of condensation. Mean velocity of gas molecules is proportional to square root of temperature, so it increases as well.
